# chosen-select not working bootstrap 3 modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

I cannot fix a chosen-select from a modal which i am following here http://jsfiddle.net/koenpunt/W6dZV/,  I cannot apply it  to my code, [please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubL8A.jpg)

I have a chosen select on its page, but not on modal, I want to apply it on my modal,

this is my code on button:

```
 <div class="text-center">
 <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
  <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br/> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>

  </div>
```

anyway, I am still applying the codes on the fiddle to mide. 
the modal:
                                           
        
     
      
        
          ×
          Modal title
        
        
           
        
        United States
        United Kingdom
        Afghanistan
        Aland Islands
        Albania
        Algeria
        American Samoa
        Andorra
        Angola
        ....
      
        
        
          Close
          Save changes

and for the script.

```
<script>
 $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('.chosen-select', this).chosen();
});
</script>
```

As you can see, I have chosen select at the background, but i cannot apply it on modal.

Comment: It seems to be working fine in the fiddle you provided.

Comment: What would you like to see happen?

Comment: but how come it'snot working to me?